why arent the new coordinates being updated in the grid?
the first grid is supposed to have S (satellite) on row 3 and column 5 (3,5) and then it will change to r(row 3 + 2 =5 and column 5 - 2 = 3 so row 5 column 3 (5,3).the function to which i refering to is movesat.its purpose is supposed to change the coord of the satelite object to a new one
class Space {
protected:
    static const int rows = 10;
    static const int cols = 10;
    char space[rows][cols];

public:
    Space() {
        // Fill the matrix with '*'
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                space[i][j] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
void setSymbol(int x, int y, char symbol) {
        if (x >= 0 && x < rows && y >= 0 && y < cols) {
                 cout << "Setting symbol '" << symbol << "' at position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
            space[x-1][y-1] = symbol; // Place the symbol in the matrix
        } else {
            cout << "Invalid position!" << endl;
        }
    }
    void printSpace() {
        // Display the matrix with '*'
        cout << "Printing space matrix:" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
                cout << space[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        } cout<<"___________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"_________"<<counter++<<"_________"<<endl;
    cout<<"___________________"<<endl;
    }
};

class Satellite : public Space {
private:
    int pos_x;
    int pos_y;

public:
    Satellite(int x, int y) : pos_x(x), pos_y(y) {}
void placeInSpace(Space &space) {
        space.setSymbol(pos_x, pos_y, 'S');
    }
void movesat(int a,int b){
    cout<<"moving sat "<<endl;
pos_x += a;
pos_y += b;
cout << "New satellite position: (" << pos_x << ", " << pos_y << ")" << endl;
placeInSpace(*this);
cout<<"sat moved"<<endl;
}

i tried adding a few statement on each of the function to see if the function is being used and to find where the problem is but i didnt find anything.
this is the output
Setting symbol 'S' at position (3, 5)
Printing space matrix:
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * S * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
___________________
_________0_________
___________________
moving sat
New satellite position: (5, 4)
Setting symbol 'S' at position (5, 4)
sat moved
Printing space matrix:
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * S * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
___________________
_________1_________
___________________

and this is the desired output , i changed the output physically
Setting symbol 'S' at position (3, 5)
Printing space matrix:
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * S * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
___________________
_________0_________
___________________
moving sat
New satellite position: (5, 4)
Setting symbol 'S' at position (5, 4)
sat moved
Printing space matrix:
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * S * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
___________________
_________1_________
___________________


Mismatch here in setSymbol(): if (x >= 0 && x < rows && y >= 0 && y < cols) {  . . .   space[x-1][y-1]  . If x is 0, bounds check passes, but access is out of bounds.

Too many compiler errors to be worth investigating the problem further: https://godbolt.org/z/P61Yod1nM . I recommend updating the question with a [mre] (MRE). Assuming making the MRE doesn't end early with you spotting and fixing the mistake.

I would also avoid having a space object with a member also called space. Confuses the heck out of the reader.

My crystal ball thinks that the object you're modifying and the object you're printing are different objects.
